# Check if a file has a certain string in its name C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm programming a tool in C++ to remove the 000.exe malware. The malware creates a lot of files on the desktop named "UR NEXT UR NEXT UR NEXT" etc. My first step is to remove all these files from the desktop. What can I do to check every file on the desktop and for each one that contains the string "UR NEXT" somewhere in the file name, delete it. I have a basic structure of my program already written but I'm really stuck figuring out the user's username folder, then deleting ever file containing "UR NEXT" on the desktop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I already have an elevation added to the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string answer;
    cout << "=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=\n000.exe Removal Tool\n\nby OrcaTech\n\nThis tool can be used to remove the 000.exe malware from your Windows PC. Type \"y\" below and press [ENTER] to begin the removal process.\n=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "y")
    {
        cout << "Starting Removal Process..." << endl;
        cout << "Your computer will restart multiple times." << endl;
        //Stop "run away" spam message boxes
        system("taskkill /f /im runaway.exe");
        //Change the wallpaper back to the default.
        const wchar_t* path = L"%SystemRoot%\\Web\\Wallpaper\\Windows\\img0.jpg";
        SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        /* code to delete all files on desktop containing UR NEXT goes here */
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    } else {
       exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio and likely targeting Windows, you may find [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and friends do pretty much exactly what you want. If not, the [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) added in C++17 makes getting directory lists trivial.

Comment: That seems like what I want. Can you provide a code example, please?

Comment: If you're asking about `FindFirstFile`, there's a good, if simplistic, example at the bottom of [the documentation page I linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea). Beneath the example is a [link to a much more comprehensive example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory). Give both a read and then take a shot at using them. Ask questions about the examples or your attempt, if you have any. It's generally better to come to Stack Overflow with code or research than without.

Comment: You can use %USERPROFILE% to access user's username folder.

Comment: I really don't understand how I'm supposed to implement the code in to my project. I edited my question and added my code that I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` to iterate over every file in the desktop folder and remove the files with specific names:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::filesystem::path> filesToRemove;
    for (const auto& i : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("path_to_desktop"))
    {

        std::string fileName = i.path().filename().string();
        if (fileName.find("UR NEXT") != std::string::npos)
        {
            filesToRemove.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }
    for (const auto& i : filesToRemove)
    {
        std::filesystem::remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a wrong suggestion. You should not remove files while iterating through a directory. Edited.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try it after school.

Comment: I'm putting the code you sent in to Visual Studio but there is one problem. When I highlight the word "filesystem" (as in `std::vector<std::filesystem::path> filesToRemove;`), it says "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name" even though I included it in the header.

Comment: You need to enable C++ 17 support to use `std::filesystem`.